# comparing strings in java using == vs .equals

Tags: java

So I understand that the == checks for equality in the reference number (the address of objects in memory). And the .equals() checks for the content of the objects.

```
String s = "test";
String s2 = "test";
```

I'm creating two different string objects but yet, I get the following:

```
s == s2;  //true, I dont know why, aren't s and s2 two different objects with 
            different internal values
s.equals(s2); //true, which I understand
```

Comment: this has been explained in detail in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> aren't s and s2 two different objects

No. `s` and `s2` refer to the same Object that has been interned in the `String` pool

Comment: so whenever you say `String something = "something"` the reference variable `something` is referring to the same object?

Comment: Yes. provided that `"something"` has already been interned. You could use `new String("test")` to explicitly create a different object to return `false` for the 1st test